# JavaScript issue involving value

Tags: javascript

I could not figure out how to transitions this line :

```
if (form.userid.value == "1" && form.pwd.value == "1")
```

Into something like this:

```
if (form.userid.value == "1","2" && form.pwd.value == "1","2")
```

As an example, if a user would enter in a form value for user/pass they could enter 1 or 2 on the user/pass
sorta like a login page with very low security supporting multiple unique logins.

Comment: `["1","2"].includes(form.userid.value)`

Comment: @JaromandaX how would i add this? like this?                                   if(form.userid.value == ["1","2"].includes(form.userid.value) && form.pwd.value == ["1","2"].includes(form.userid.value))

Comment: try it and see!

Comment: I can't see what "doesn't work"

Comment: https://justpaste.it/9bb0e

Comment: I'm mega tired so sorry if I'm being weird about everything

Answer (score 1):

- Using `||`:

```js
if ((form.userid.value === "1" || form.userid.value === "2") && (form.pwd.value === "1" || form.pwd.value === "2"))
```

- Using `includes`:

```js
if (["1", "2"].includes(form.userid.value) && ["1", "2"].includes(form.pwd.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp)

```
let arr = ["1", "2"];
```

Now use `includes`, with your array

```
if (arr.includes(form.userid.value) && arr.includes(form.pwd.value))
```

`includes` returns true if the array contains the element, and false if not

Answer (score 0):

```
if(["1","2"].includes(form.userid.value) && ["1","2"].includes(form.pwd.value))
```

will work. But if someone uses say user1's id and user2's pwd then also he will be able to login. This is not a good practice.

Comment: Any way to past the problem

Comment: Give me more information about how you are storing your user data(in database or some object) then i will be able to solve your problem.

Comment: im storing it in the html

Comment: Create an array of user and then loop through each user to compare userid and pwd.  var users = [
    {
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'admin123'
    },
    {
      username: 'test',
      password: 'user'
    }
   ];
   
   
 function check(form,users){
  return users.some(user=>user.username==form.userid.value && user.password == form.pwd.value)
 }